# Existence of Religion in India only

Tags: other-religions, india

Why the religion start from India only?? why not from other country??
If the first Lord took birth,why he/she took birth in india only or if he give birth to demigods,why only in india??
why not pakistan??why not america or anywhere else??

Comment: Hinduism claims "Vasuddhava Kutumbakam" (वसुधैव कुटुम्बकम) . The world is One Family.

Comment: Before advent of Abrahamic Religions such as Islam, Christianity, Sanatana Dharma was followed everywhere. Many idols of Hindu Gods were found in other countries. Worshiping Sun, Snakes  were common. With time new Religions emerged there, which are against idol worship. Probably, they might have not known about **power of Vedic Mantras** by which we invoke God into them. There are many similarities among Norse Mythology, Greek Mythology and Hindu Mythology.

Comment: @TheDestroyer please give me the reference for that if you are saying  this.